# Ruby on Rails, transform form data in url

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, forms, url

i need some help for my application,I am creating an app using an api to search data relative to an username.

So i have done a form to type the username but on submit, i want the url to be like:

`mydomain.com/search/myusername/`  instead of
`mydomain.com/search?username=myusername`

Because my route is :
`get 'players/:username', to: 'players#show'`

Do you guys have any idea ?

Thanks a lot

Comment: on submit let the url be like that and then from controller find the player using the search param, then if successfully found, redirect to the player show page.

Comment: Thank you but i don't store players, that's the problem :/ I dont use any models

Comment: but then where do you search from?

Comment: I am using an API with Faraday, and i need to specify the username in order to get datas

Comment: ok, in that case, use js to stop the form submission. and manually build the url using the form value entered and redirect to that url. All using javascript

Comment: I'll try, thank you